# Mean spectra over multiple pixels from datacube

Tags: python, pixel, spectrum, fits, data-cube

I have a fits datacube with galactic longitude, latitude and velocity in the 3 axis. To extract the spectrum from the datacube at a particular pixel value of longitude and latitude, I use the function

```
cube[:, 1935, 1407].quicklook()
plt.show()
```

and the image is extracted with the function

```
cube.to_pvextractor()
plt.show()
```

A sample spectrum [image: spectrum]
and a zoomed image [image] is attached here.

The bright spots are the detections. How do I use several pixels and average the spectra to get a mean spectrum so that I reduce the noise and analyze the peak? I have been trying to code this but I don't know how to proceed as I am new to python. Can anybody please give a hint?

Comment: How does upper image relate to lower-left? Why lower-right is blank? Also: the background data in the lower-left has significant noise from the instruments (clear diagonal "strips") that has to be accounted for. The most important thing: astronomical data should be processed the way the astronomers do. I'm afraid SO is not  the best place to ask this question.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the problem in my question. Just an additional query. Is there any way to take the average of several pixels and form a new spectrum?

Comment: I'm not an astronomer. If I were to tackle this all by myself, I'd do it as in 1D case: fit a 2D Gaussian to a noisy 2D signal. Actually, there are   at least 4 distinct signal sources (galaxies?) in  the data. You can pinpoint them one after another, eventually you'll have a superposition of 4 Gaussians.  You need python's scipy. Then manually estimate the result (coordinates of the signal center,  its "width" and "amplitude". Run sci-py. Take your PhD :-) BTW, are you a PhD student or is it only Master's in astronomy?

Comment: I am doing a short-term project in astronomy after completing my M.Sc in Physics. I am new to python and you have been a great help to me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Then remember to estimate the initial values of the fitted parameters, otherwise sci-py may get lost and return a completely absurd  solution. There's nothing wrong in this. When sci-py returns the solution, you must compare it against the original, experimental data to make sure sci-py has converged to the required solution.

Comment: Suppose if I create a  `subcube = cube[:, 1450:1620, 430:500]`  such that it includes the bright spot and the write  `spectrum = subcube.mean(axis=(1,2))`  will it give me an averaged spectrum?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, means, this would be a very crude estimate, most likely a highly underestimated value. No, because fitting data to a 2D Gaussian is rather simple and robust.    sci-py has all you need. Unfortunately, I don't use python nor sci-py, but I've seen it many times in action, it is a full replacement of octave/matlab, so nothing more is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spectrapepper](https://github.com/spectrapepper/spectrapepper) for this:

```
import spectrapepper as spep
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load sample data from library
x, y = spep.load_spectras()

# calculate the average spectra of the set
avg = spep.avg(y)

# plot the result compared to the data set
for i in y:
    plt.plot(x, i, lw=0.5)
plt.plot(x, avg, c='red', lw=1)
plt.show()
```

The library has also other tools for data set analysis. Check [example 6](https://spectrapepper.github.io/spectrapepper/examples.html) included in the `docs` for more options of similar nature.